# Errors after "Android Gradle Plugin Upgrade"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Environment: Windows 10, Android Studio 3.3 Canary 13

When open an app I wrote with earlier version of Android Studio I got the following message -

[image]

After the update completed successfully I get **cannot resolve method** errors (red text) for the following methods: *finish(), startActivity(), getIntent(), getSystemService, findViewById* and many more....

**The app worked fine on previous Android Studio version**

What can be the cause for these **cannot resolve method** errors ?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with your Android Studio installation. You should probably try closing and re-opening the project, re-import the gradle plugins, etc. These errors usually mean something is not getting resolved either by not finding the Android SDK or not importing gradle properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Errors after Gradle update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52741398/errors-after-gradle-update)